# ftp_fget() returns Transfer Complete error

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to download images from a remote FTP server and upload them to our own rackspace account. This goes fine for about 3000 images but then it crashes and gives me the following error:

> exception with message 'ftp_fget(): Transfer complete.'

We've tried changing the code to use `ftp_get()`, to not use a temp file to store it in, but it always resulted in the same error. It always fails on the same files, if I were to delete a couple of files that were already downloaded and run the scripts again it has no problem downloading them... it just fails again once it hits those specific images on the FTP server. I've tried downloading those images manually from the server and it worked, it seems nothing is wrong with them.

This is basically the code that does it:

```
$this->handle = ftp_connect($ftpurl);
$loggedIn = ftp_login($this->handle, $ftpusername, $ftppassword);
if ($loggedIn === false) {
    throw new Exception('Can\'t login to FTP server');
}
if ($this->handle === false) {
    throw new Exception('Could not connect to the given url');
}
ftp_pasv($this->handle, true);

$fileList = ftp_nlist($this->handle, '.');
if (count($fileList) === 0) {
    throw new Exception('No files found on FTP-server');
}

foreach($fileList as $filename) { 
    try {
        $container->getObject($filename);
        // Image already exists, rackspace has no convenient hasImage() function
    } catch (Exception $ex) {     
        $temp = tmpfile();
        ftp_fget($this->handle, $temp, $filename, FTP_BINARY);

        //upload $tmp to rackspace
    }
}
```

Any ideas what could be the issue here?

Comment: I see in the PHP comments page on this function a reference to too many open file handles.  Are you closing the $temp filehandle before uploading to Rackspace?

Comment: Yeah, we close the handle. But this also doesn't seem to be the problem since it fails on the first image it tries to download. It skips images which were downloaded before, this bit wasn't included in the above code example. I'll add it.

Comment: Is there a certain filename that triggers it?  I see that ftp_nlist does not escape filenames.  Could be just a stab in the dark, but I see nothing patently wrong with your code.

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but the file it fails on is called "H7539M_DET0.JPG" which doesn't seem like a weird name